# Initialize multiple tinymce with different mode attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

Suppose the case when we want to convert all textarea elements to  editors when the page loads.

To achieve that we can use mode "textareas"

```
mode : "textareas",
```

Then we could need to add editors to dinamically added textarea elements using mode "exact" for further use

```
mode : "exact",
```

So how we can initialize two different tinymce with different modes, or there is another way to acheive this purpuse at all?

Comment: have a look at their doc: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/get-started/multiple-editors/ section different configurations

Comment: There is no about multiple configurations with different "mode" attribute

Comment: it doesn't show an example with `mode`, but try following the same pattern: use 2 separate calls to `tinymce.init`, each one with different mode

Comment: Looks straightforward. What have you tried?